# How to write this efficiently in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like to re-write this efficiently in MATLAB.

```
n=3;
x=zeros(n);
y=x;
for 1=1:n
x(:,i)=i;
y(i,:)=i;
end
```

I tried to run it in MATLAB and get this output below

x =

```
 1     0     0
 1     0     0
 1     0     0
```

y =

```
 1     1     1
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
```

x =

```
 1     2     0
 1     2     0
 1     2     0
```

y =

```
 1     1     1
 2     2     2
 0     0     0
```

x =

```
 1     2     3
 1     2     3
 1     2     3
```

y =

```
 1     1     1
 2     2     2
 3     3     3
```

Comment: The Help Center says that questions about "Software that mathematicians use" is on-topic. We also have a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

[x,y] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n);

Comment: +1 Or use just `[x,y] = meshgrid(1:n);`

Answer (score 2):

When hard-coded,

```
x=[1 2 3;1 2 3;1 2 3]; y=x';
```

will do. If not (`n` arbitrary), you can use

```
x=1:n;           % Creates a "template row" [1 2 3 ... n]
x=repmat(x,n,1); % Stacks this row n times [1 2 3 ... n; 
                                            1 2 3 ... n;
                                                   ... ;
                                            1 2 3 ... n] (n-by-n matrix)
y=x';            % Creates the transpose
```

Comment: I tried I dont get the same results

Comment: @joke Well, what do you get then?
Maybe use `help repmat` to ensure the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=ones(3,1)*(1:3);
y=(1:3)'*ones(1,3);
```

Alternatively, you can set y equals transposition of x.